# How to format CRM "Date Only" field to string with Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker, dynamics-crm-2013, clickdimension

Im trying to build a email template with Freemarker/Clickdimensions plugin in CRM 2013. I have a "Date only" field on an entity which for example contains the date 2017-04-17. I want this date to show as the following: Monday 17 april.

This is done with Freemarker and I have tried the following:

```
<#assign x  = Recipient.field_booking.field_scheduleddate?time>
${x?string.full}
```

This doesnt seem to work. Im not getting any result at all, just an empty line.
Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I will assume that `field_scheduleddate` is a string (not a `java.util.Date`).

At `?time` FreeMarker should throw and exception saying something like that the string doesn't follow the expected pattern. I suspect the framework you are using catches and suppresses that exception (which makes using FreeMarker much much harder). Check the logs, maybe it's there.

You want to deal with a date-only value there, hence you should use `?date`, as `?time` is for time-only values. Also, `field_scheduleddate` apparently uses ISO 8601 format, so unless the `date_format` configuration setting is set to ISO, you will have to use `?date.iso` (supported since FreeMarker 2.3.21).

As of printing the date, `?string.full` should work, but usually you should set `date_format` globally to the format you prefer, and then you can simply write `${x}`.

(Also note that `#assign` is unnecessary above, as you can put arbitrarily complex expression inside `${}`.)